# Automating building a table from web sources in MS Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to build a table indicating a number of things available in a given market. To do this I access the sites with relevant information and copy numbers to a table each day. I would love to automate that process. I know I could import the data tables from sites in questions into separate Excel sheets using the Data -> From Web function, but how to automate this? That is how to make a VBA script that will run those imports and then create another row in the first sheet copying relevant data from other sheets along with the current date?

Comment: How much are you looking to automate? It's pretty easy to set those connections up to refresh and add any new data as needed without any VBA.

Comment: Agreed with @CLockeWork that this might could be done with refreshable web queries and some vlookups.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It does depend on the style of web site and how consistently it is updated, but it has a nice visual editor to help you explore the web site content.

Power Query has lots of other features to help massage the data once it has been downloaded.

Here's a nice walkthrough of some of those functions:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/power-query-101-HA103993784.aspx